# Windows XP SP2 or SP3 archive or downloads?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update, service-pack

I need a test machine for testing on Windows XP. I have a copy of 32-bit Windows XP I purchased years ago. The Operating System installed fine on some old hardware.

I'm now trying to update the OS to Service Pack 2 or 3. The best I can tell, Microsoft has broken all the public links for the product. For example, I can't find a download for XP Service Pack 2 or 3 in the download area. And all the links provided on TechNet at [Installing Windows XP Service Pack 3 (SP3)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc507836.aspx) are broken. The [Windows XP Service Pack 2 website](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=26347) is also dead.

Its probably worth noting that Windows Update is also broken at the moment, so I can't use it to update the machine. Its one of the reasons I want to get to the SP2 mark. Microsoft's FTP site also appears dead. I have not used it in years, but I know it used to work.

Where are the downloads for 32-bit Windows XP SP2 or SP3? Where does Microsoft provide the archives?

Comment: You need install/slipstream both SP2 & SP3 if you have SP1 installation CD. To slipstream and adjust your installation CD can use nLite.

Comment: _"Windows Update is also broken at the moment, so I can't use it to update the machine. Its one of the reasons I want to get to the SP2 mark. Microsoft's FTP site also appears dead. I have not used it in years, but I know it used to work."_ Yeah and then XP went end-of-life. It's dead.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I use an archive I built from an outdated version of [WSUS offline update](http://download.wsusoffline.net/) - in case I need to stand up a windows XP system. You need [version 9.21](http://download.wsusoffline.net/wsusoffline921.zip) or older as its the last version that supported XP. Since its downloading the updates directly from MS, and gets the full/offline installers *and* automatically applies them,  these are the official updates *and* you don't need to rely on windows update for at least the initial update.

This should get your XP box completely up to date, and as of mid december 2016 (when I'm posting it), it seems to update still. This is the *best* option since it should get your system as patched up as possible, and lets you do so even if XP patches are no longer hosted if you already downloaded them.

It also has lovely logging, and lists of file locations and it lists http://xpsp.dlservice.microsoft.com/download/d/3/0/d30e32d8-418a-469d-b600-f32ce3edf42d/WindowsXP-KB936929-SP3-x86-ENU.exe as the location for windows XP SP3. Of course, this link is likely to die at some point, and I have no XP boxen to test it from. 
I *strongly* recommend building your own offline update archive if you think you need it

As of 2017, WSUS offline update v9.21 can't seem to download XP patches. The link for XP3 is still valid.

Answer (score 4):

Do you already have things installed on the OS? If not, it might be faster if you would simply find an ISO for Windows XP that comes with SP3 installed already.

Otherwise, what do you currently have? SP1? Have you installed all regular updates?

I was able to find the [Microsoft Update Catalog](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=7477af62-8f9b-4f32-9daf-7ab452e52396) site which has links for [SP3](http://www.download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/software/dflt/2008/04/windowsxp-kb936929-sp3-x86-enu_c81472f7eeea2eca421e116cd4c03e2300ebfde4.exe) and [SP2](http://www.download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3-19990518/cabpool/xpsp2_33a8fef60d48ae1f2c4feea27111af5ceca3c4f6.exe).

Once you do get SP3, you should get the [Unofficial SP4](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Signatures-Updates/Windows-XP-SP4-Unofficial.shtml) to download all updates post-SP3 and receive new updates from Microsoft until April 2019 (I have tested this myself).

EDIT: I should note here, that while this method still works, you will only get updates up until 2019 April 9th, which is when POSReady 2009 (embedded XP) support ends. If you are still using Windows XP past this date, you need to switch away from it, or disconnect from the Internet, to remain secure.

Comment: I think that product keys for Windows XP (without SP), SP1, SP2 and SP3 work exclusivelly on those versions. If you want to keep the Windows XP box legal, you need to have this into consideration. I remember having troubles activating a Windows XP SP3 with an SP2 key.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I tried the catalog, but Microsoft appears to have broken that, too. I can reach it on an modern OS, but both IE and Firefox gets an error on XP. Transferring onto the XP machine is a bit painful at the moment because I have to burn a CD. Microsoft is not making it easy.

Comment: @jww Why not use a flash drive? Also, you could try setting up a network share, see if Firefox can download FileZilla.

Comment: Thanks Aaron - The machine was modified for unusual testing The ports were epoxied closed in a hardened installation. The IDE headers are still available so i could use an internal CD ROM.

Comment: A third option if you're still having trouble is boot a live Linux session and use that to copy the files.

Answer (score 4):

Go to windows update catalogue and type xp (or only KB936929) in search field  http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=xp
You can find there many others helpful packs.
Good luck

Comment: Assuming you know SP3 is KB936929. xp SP3 seems to work too tho.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I tried the catalog, but Microsoft appears to have broken that, too. I can reach it on an modern OS, but both IE and Firefox gets an error on XP. Transferring onto the XP machine is a bit painful at the moment because I have to burn a CD. Microsoft is not making it easy.

Comment: You can use LAN to transfer, or copy download link and use it directly on XP

Answer (score 3):

I know it costs money, but if you do this for a living, it's money well spent: Get a Microsoft Developer Network subscription. Though they recently migrated MSDN to visualstudio.com, it appears that all the old downloads are still there, including Windows XP, e.g.,:

```
Windows XP Professional KN with Service Pack 3 (x86) - CD (English)
Released: 5/1/2008
SHA1: 29aafdd5abd8cc48eb43d262797d80676e4993fb
File name: en_windows_xp_professional_kn_with_service_pack_3_x86_cd_x14-92432.iso
```

Even Windows 3.1 is still available for download. Or, for that matter, MS-DOS 6.0 and 6.22. This is one of the reasons why I maintain a subscription.

Comment: This will get you up to SP3, but not necessarily the latest updates for that version.

Comment: True, but Windows Update still works. You just don't get any new updates (although even that has a workaround, as you can use a Registry setting to pretend that your XP is a point-of-sale installation, which remains supported until 2019; see, e.g., http://www.zdnet.com/article/registry-hack-enables-continued-updates-for-windows-xp/)

Comment: @Bob: "Latest updates"... for Windows XP?

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice trick you can pull. Microsoft puts the name and the SHA1 hash of the image file [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/#FileId=15551).
All you need to do is search for the file name online, download it, then verify it has the right hash before you use it (so you know it hasn't been tampered with).
Just Googling brings up a lot of results for me.

Note that you need to find the appropriate image file (retail vs. OEM vs. volume license etc.).

Also note that this *may* (or may not) violate copyright laws in your country. You're on your own there.

Comment: This is not necessarily reliable - I'm not sure about XP, but I know some MSDN images are different from the retail version, therefore the hash verification will fail. And of course the MSDN version might not accept a retail key.

Comment: @Bob: Hence my second paragraph...